# Is there a single word that means "root of the issue"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that means "root of the issue" or "cause of the problem".

I found the single words "origin", "cause", and "basis", but they do not indicate the *negativity* experienced from an issue or a problem.

I'm looking to say "I found the _____!".

Comment: While *crux* does mean "root of the issue" but would not work in your sentence.

Comment: @nnnnnn I think culprit is a great option.  Why don't you add it as an answer?

Comment: For some reason at the time I didn't think it was adequate as an answer so I just posted a comment to at least let you know of the option. I didn't delete my comment though - I assume a moderator must have found it inappropriate and deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps strangely, I'd say the most idiomatic word for *cause of the problem* is actually [**problem**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/problem) itself:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2 b** : a source of perplexity, distress, or vexation

In short:

> I found the problem!

Since this sense of the word means *source*, it already has the implied meaning of *source of the issue* or, in other words, *cause of the problem*. It's somewhat recursive, but it's still natural usage.

---

Another word, which seems to have been suggested in a now-deleted comment under the question, is [**culprit**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/culprit):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **3** : the source or cause of a problem
>   // Lack of exercise and poor diet are the main *culprits* in heart disease.

In the example sentence used in its definition, *culprit* seems a better choice than *problem* would be.

---

However, in the sentence *I found the ___!*, [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20found%20the%20problem%2C%20I%20found%20the%20culprit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20found%20the%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20found%20the%20culprit%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20found%20the%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20found%20the%20culprit%3B%2Cc0) suggests that *problem* is the more common word, at least in print.

[image: I found the problem]